# Unable to create a New Connection in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a new connection in Oracle SQL Developer.
Below are the inputs i am providing and its failing :

1. Connection Name: HR_ORCL
2. Username: hr
3. Password: (system password)
4. Hostname: localhost
5. SID: orcl

Clicking Test Connection .

```
Failure
Test Failed: ORA-01017:invalid username/password;login denied
```

Comment: What's unclear about "invalid username/password"?

Comment: I have tried using the default username provided in the http://www.oracle.com and using the {system password} . I am doing correct configuration, also the Username and Password supplied are correct . Still i am getting that error.

Comment: if you want to use the system password, you need to login as 'system' - not HR. HR is sample account, it may not even be on your database. and if it is, it's likely to be locked

Comment: - login as dba or user with dba privileges.Then run `ALTER USER HR IDENTIFIED by password;`  . use this password to login as HR.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith I did try using the Username as : sys and Password as :{system password} but still i was facing the issue.

Comment: @kaushikNayak but in order to login via user or dba , What password should i (provide)supply there while creating a new connection. Thank You .

Comment: The password you provided during installation.

Comment: @AnuragAnand then you forgot to set the connection type to AS SYSDBA, or you have the wrong password, or you have the wrong database.

Comment: passwords are case sensitive by the way, and you can also try the SYSTEM user